# Change ROM Samsumg S7 Edge

Tags: samsung, custom-roms, rom, stock-rom, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

I have a Samsung s7 Edge cell phone, I bought it in the US with the Verizon company,
I returned to Mexico and I am working with the Telcel company, the model is GS G935V, my question is: I Can install a ROM SM G935F Telcel?

Comment: Verizon? Give it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Change mi ROM of SM-G935V to SM-G935U and all Verizon applications have been removed.

I share the ROM link in case someone wants to change it.

[SM G935U](https://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/galaxy-s7-edge/SM-G935U/)

Comment: of that list, wich g935U firmeware do i Have select? there are a lot of firmeware, wich do you use?

Comment: I selected Unknown(XAS)